# Elixir floating point division accuracy

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm observing some unexpected floating point behaviour in Elixir.

```
4.7 / 0.1 = 47.0 (good!)
4.8 / 0.1 = 47.9999999999 (bad!)
4.9 / 0.1 = 49 (good!)
```

While I understand the limitations of fp accuracy, in this case, the answer just looks wrong.

Curiously, I tried this in python as well, and got the same result, which is even more mysterious. When I changed the format to `4.8 * (1/0.1)`, I get the right answer (48.0).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a normal behavior for IEEE 754 floating point numbers, and unrelated to erlang/elixir. Python or Nodejs would return the same thing.

For more information, you can read this [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014).

Answer (score 0):

> While I understand the limitations of fp accuracy

Clearly not :-)

As always, if you need decimal precision, use [Decimal](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/):

```elixir
iex(2)> Decimal.div(Decimal.new("4.8"), Decimal.new("0.1"))
#Decimal<48>
iex(3)> Decimal.mult(Decimal.new("4.8"), Decimal.new("10"))
#Decimal<48.0>
```